# Invalid use of 'void' in C++ when using struct and classes

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I have 1 compiler error. It is from this line in my code:

```
cout << myClass->Get_Type().description;
```

Where as Get_Type() is:

```
void Tile::Get_Type() {  
    return &myStruct;  
}
```

I'm not quite sure what I am doing wrong. Or what for that matter could be going wrong.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A function with a return type of `void` cannot return anything (that's what the `void` means:  the function does not return anything).  You are trying to return something (the address of `myStruct`).

You either need to return nothing (i.e. change your return to just be `return;` or remove it entirely) or change the return type of the function from `void` to a pointer to whatever the type of `myStruct` is.

Comment: FFWD to 2020 -- This is why we have the `std::optional` these days, to be able to return nothing, aka the "empty"  state.

Answer (score 2):

Your Get_Type() method has return type void whereas it should have the return type of myStruct.

If your struct is declared like this:

```
struct S {
  char* description;
}
```

your Get_Type should return a pointer of type S:

```
S* Tile::Get_Type(){
  return &myStruct;
}
```

assuming that myStruct is declared as:

```
S myStruct;
```

in the class declaration.

Comment: You can format your code by indenting it 4 spaces or selecting it and clicking the `010` button... There is also inline markup etc., see the editing help for more.

Comment: Thanks, I knew it was there but the javascript creating the edit buttons was blocked before.

Answer (score 1):

Get_Type returns void. So it can't be a structure with an element named discription. Or description.

You need, instead

```
TypeOfMyStruct * Tile::Get_Type() { ... }
```

And then you need:

```
foo->GetType()->description
```

because that's a pointer you want to return, not a reference.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to return an object from a function which is defined as having no return type.

What should  Get_Type be returning?  It looks like you are trying to return an address to `myStruct`.  If this is intended, you need your function definition to look like so:

```
TypeOfMyStruct* Tile::Get_Type() {
return &myStruct;
}
```

Replace "TypeOfMyStruct" with the actual type of `myStruct`.

If you don't want anything returned, then just remove the `return &myStruct;` line and that will fix your problem.   However I suspect this is not the case.

Answer (score 0):

A function with "void" return type will cannot return anything.
So, you should change the return type to myStuct type.

Comment: What is the contribution of this answer compared to the older ones?